# Python:Agrupar valores de una lista

Tags: python

Tengo una lista:

```
      print(piezas_vendidos)

      ["['Queso']", "['Queso', 'Queso']", "['Queso', 'Queso']", "['Queso', 'Queso']", "['Queso']", "['Leche', 'Leche', 'Queso']", "['Queso', 'Queso']", "['Queso', 'Queso']", "['Queso', 'Queso']", "['Queso']", "['Queso', 'Queso', 'Queso']"]
```

Me gustaría obtener a partir de esta lista una lista como esta:
{'Queso':19,'Leche':2}

¿Cómo se podría hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada elemento de tu lista es en realidad otra lista, sólo que está almacenada como una cadena de caracteres (por ejemplo `"['Queso']"`, en vez de simplemente `['Queso']`.

Yo te diría que revisaras cómo generas esas sub-listas para evitar meterlas como cadenas, y tenerlas como listas propiamente dichas. Si resuelves ese problema, es decir, si tu lista `piezas_vendidas` contuviera:

```
[['Queso'], ['Queso', 'Queso'], ['Queso', 'Queso'], ['Queso', 'Queso'], 
['Queso'], ['Leche', 'Leche', 'Queso'], ['Queso', 'Queso'], ['Queso', 'Queso']
['Queso', 'Queso'], ['Queso'], ['Queso', 'Queso', 'Queso']]
```

Entonces bastaría ir recorriendo esa lista para después recorrer cada una de las sublistas e ir incrementando un diccionario en el que las claves serían los items. Para esto último es muy conveniente usar un `defaultdic()` pues así los elementos que aparecen por primera vez se crean automáticamente sin tener que asignarles un cero "manualmente".

Con este enfoque:

```
from collections import defaultdict

conteo = defaultdict(int)
for sublista in piezas_vendidas:
  for item in sublista:
    conteo[item] += 1

print(dict(conteo))
```

Resultado: `{'Queso': 19, 'Leche': 2}`

Ahora bien, tal como lo tienes (siendo cada elemento de `piezas_vendidas` una cadena) también se puede resolver *evaluando* esa cadena, para obtener así la sublista que hay en ella. Esta solución sería muy similar a la anterior, sólo que añadiendo `eval()` en cada sublista:

```
from collections import defaultdict

conteo = defaultdict(int)
for sublista in piezas_vendidas:
  for item in eval(sublista):
    conteo[item] += 1

print(dict(conteo))
```

No obstante es preferible la primera solución, pues `eval()` puede fallar si alguna de las sublistas contiene algo que no sea interpretable por python. Incluso puede llegar a ser peligroso si algún elemento de `piezas_vendidas` fuese código python malicioso.

Comment: Funciona correctamente de las dos formas! Muchas gracias @abulafia